# C# .NET 4.0 generic covariance problem with cast exception

Tags: .net, generics, c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

I have been battling with this for a while, so any help would be appreciated. Here's the scenario i am faced with on C# .NET 4.0.

```
public interface ITableBusinessLogicLayerIn<in TTableRecord> : IBusinessLogicLayer
    where TTableRecord : ITableRecord
{
// No definition
}

public interface ITableBusinessLogicLayerOut<out TTableRecord> : IBusinessLogicLayer
    where TTableRecord : ITableRecord
{
// No definition
}
```

I have an object which implements both interfaces. Code compiles fine. But at runtime, I am able to cast this object as follows:

```
(ITableBusinessLogicLayerOut<ITableRecord>)obj
```

but not as this:

```
(ITableBusinessLogicLayerIn<ITableRecord>)obj
```

This is highly confusing, i'm not sure what i am doing wrong. Someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure this has something to do with the fact that "in" generic parameters are mostly used for lambdas and methods and not for classes, since they're all about passing a value "in". That's all I've got though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contravariance (in) allows you to cast an object with a type parameter of a less-specific type to one of a more-specific type. For example, you can't pass an object to a type the expects a string, so you can't cast a type that expects a string to a type that expects an object.  See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183%28d=lightweight%29.aspx

Given the following example:

```
class MyTableRecord : ITableRecord { }
ITableBusinessLogicLayerIn<ITableRecord> inA;
ITableBusinessLogicLayerIn<MyTableRecord> inB;
ITableBusinessLogicLayerOut<ITableRecord> outA;
ITableBusinessLogicLayerOut<MyTableRecord> outB;
```

You can assign `inB` to `inA`, but not the reverse.  You can assign `outA` to `outB`, but not the reverse.

Comment: Hi Talljoe. I need to work with the generic interface ITableBusinessLogicLayerIn, so that i may Add, Update any type of ITableRecord object, i.e. UserRecord, RoleRecord, MenuRecord, etc. How would i achieve this?

Comment: For what you are doing you probably don't need variance.  A simple generic will work.  Variance is only if you want to be able to use one type for another type where they are both the same generic base but have different type parameters (Like using IEnumerable<string> in some place that expects an IEnumerable<object>). You generally have to choose one direction or the other, you can't do both (or you essentially end up with invariance).